# Trying to have the same RANGE show up in multiple sheets

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am trying to build a system for sorting all my money transactions.

Say one sheet, RAW_DATA has all the .CSV data. 
I have the data defined as "RAW_TRANSACTIONS" ... It starts at cell A2.

All the following sheets are sourcing from the same sheet and it shows up just fine as long as I type =RAW_TRANSACTIONS in A2 of the current sheet. So if I want to start the data at A7, I can't.

Is there a way around this? Offsetting cells somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need (not certain I understand the requirement!) is to press:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the 'current' sheet.